# Phonegap/Cordova Android App - Automated test through robotium

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, robotium

I received an Android apk and I need to perform some blackbox automated tests on this app.

I successfully set-up the Robotium environment and test suite, but as soon as I launch the JUnit I run into the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.robotium.solo.RobotiumWebClient cannot be cast to org.apache.cordova.CordovaChromeClient
    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.setWebChromeClient(CordovaWebView.java:316)
    at com.robotium.solo.RobotiumWebClient$1.run(RobotiumWebClient.java:59)
    at android.app.Instrumentation$SyncRunnable.run(Instrumentation.java:1858)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5867)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

In the test method I simply inserted:

```
solo.clickOnText("Login");
```

The first page inside the app is a section with a button with the "Login" label.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Cordova is not supported by Robotium:
https://github.com/RobotiumTech/robotium/issues/757